# Matplotlib 3.0.2 produced misaligned date axis with twinx and major minor formatter and locator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a timeseries graph. I have a major and minor tick formatter and locator to format and locate the dates. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Set major and minor tick formatter and locators
major_loc = mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(0), interval=1)
major_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b')
minor_loc = mdates.DayLocator()

# Read Sample CSV
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/APophale/sfm-shiny/master/data.csv', index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])
month_yr = df.index[0].strftime('%b-%Y')
dates = df.index.to_pydatetime()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17,11))

#Plot flow
ax_flow = plt.subplot(411)
ax_flow.plot_date(dates, df['Flow (MGD)'], '-', linewidth=1.0, color='black')
ax_flow.xaxis.set_major_locator(major_loc)
ax_flow.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)
ax_flow.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_loc)
ax_flow.grid('on', which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75)
ax_flow.set_ylabel('Flow (MGD)')
ax_flow.set_title('RGCOBF1 Midway Rd', loc='right')

#Plot rainfall
ax_rain = ax_flow.twinx()
ax_rain.bar(dates, df['Rainfall (inches)'], width=0.10)
ax_rain.xaxis.set_major_locator(major_loc)
ax_rain.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)
ax_rain.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_loc)
ax_rain.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax_rain.invert_yaxis()
ax_rain.set_ylabel('Rainfall (inches)')

#Plot depth
ax_dep = plt.subplot(412)
ax_dep.plot_date(dates, df['Depth (inches)'], '-', linewidth=1.0, color='red')
ax_dep.xaxis.set_major_locator(major_loc)
ax_dep.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)
ax_dep.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_loc)
ax_dep.grid('on', which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75)
ax_dep.set_ylabel('Depth (inches)')
ax_dep.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')

#Plot velocity
ax_vel = ax_dep.twinx()
ax_vel.plot_date(dates, df['Velocity (ft/s)'], '--', linewidth=1.0, color='green')
ax_vel.xaxis.set_major_locator(major_loc)
ax_vel.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)
ax_vel.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_loc)
ax_vel.set_ylabel('Velocity (ft/s)')
ax_vel.tick_params(axis='y', colors='green')

#Plot scatter
ax_scatter = plt.subplot(413)
ax_scatter.scatter(x=df['Velocity (ft/s)'], y=df['Depth (inches)'], s=5)
ax_scatter.set_ylabel('Depth (inches)')
ax_scatter.set_xlabel('Velocity (ft/s)')

#Plot table
ax_table = plt.subplot(414)
rows = ('Min', 'Max', 'Average', 'Total')
columns = ('Flow (MGD)', 'Rainfall (inches)', 'Velocity (ft/s)', 'Depth (inches)')
table_data = [[np.around(df['Flow (MGD)'].min(), 3), '', np.around(df['Velocity (ft/s)'].min(), 3),
               np.around(df['Depth (inches)'].min(), 3)],
              [np.around(df['Flow (MGD)'].max(), 3), '', np.around(df['Velocity (ft/s)'].max(), 3),
               np.around(df['Depth (inches)'].max(), 3)],
              [np.around(df['Flow (MGD)'].mean(), 3), '', np.around(df['Velocity (ft/s)'].mean(), 3),
               np.around(df['Depth (inches)'].mean(), 3)],
              [np.around(df['Flow (MGD)'].sum()*0.0104167, 3), np.around(df['Rainfall (inches)'].sum(), 3),
               '', '']
              ]

ax_table.axis('tight')
ax_table.axis('off')
table = ax_table.table(cellText=table_data, rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
table.set_fontsize(10)
table.scale(1, 1.5)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.15, top=0.92)

plt.plot()
```

My output looks like this. you can see that in the top graph, the date axis is misaligned. I am using `matplotlib 3.0.2`. I am not sure what's wrong. I tried commenting out the formatter and locator for `ax_rain` but it doesn't work.

[image: Result]

Comment: There might be a more elegant solution, but I'd set the minimum and maximum X based on the minimum and maximum values in the data, and I'd force the ticks to an interval you'd prefer.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim

Comment: Maybe you want to share a [mcve]?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Updated.

Comment: Looking at the data, all axes are correct. So you would just either share the axes,or set the same `xlim` for both.